# How to get varbinary length as part of the model (i.e. calculated field) in Entity Framework?

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, mapping

I have the following model:

```
public class TestModel
{
    public byte[] File { get; set; }
}
```

which maps `File` to a `varbinary(max)` column in SQL Server.

Now I want to get file length without loading the data. I can do that by

```
context.Test.Select(x => SqlFunctions.DataLength(x.File)).ToList();
```

How can I extend my model to have `FileLength` in it as an automatically calculated field in it? Eg something like

```
public class TestModel
{
    public byte[] File { get; set; }

    [MapToDBFunction(SqlFunctions.DataLength)] <== WHAT SHOULD BE HERE??
    public int? FileLength { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not in the entity, the code to calculate it could only determine that by first loading it. I believe a solution that would suit your needs is to bind that entity to a view rather than a table. The view can then have a computed column for the file length.